# bootstrap mobile table style for scrollable part

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have modified table style for bootstrap as below

```
table.table{
    background: #0D0E0E;
    color: #ccc; 
}
```

But above style is not working for scrollable part for table in iphone.I cant replicate it in desktop , So I have attached my screenshot below.This how style dont work when I scroll to right.

[image]